# How to share a link to a firebase development environment when using firebase emulators?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ngrok, firebase-tools

In my development local environment, I'm using Firebase emulators for **Hosting**, **Firestore** and **Functions**.

[image]

I'm used to share a link with other people during development by using `ngrok`. I also use it to test on mobile devices during development.

This is the script:

```
"share": "ngrok http 80 -host-header=\"dev.myproject.com:80\"",
```

It works fine as far as redirecting to my dev domain host, which is `dev.myproject.com`.

But the emulators services become unavailable when you are accessing this link through a different device, i.e: a different PC or a mobile device.

Obviously, the `firebase` package is looking for those `localhost` emulators, which are only running in my local environment.

What is the workaround in this case? How to share a dev environment with other people / other devices when using firebase emulators? Is there an easy to do this?

Do I have to create an extra Firebase project to deploy the test version and its data and files? How do people usually handle this?

Answer (score 3):

We are currently trying to do this using `ngrok` as well.

We are barely testing if it works, and so far it is doing so. So I'll share our work around with you.

What we do is

- Start emulator `firebase emulators:start` (`--import seedData` if using )
- Expose your server to the internet using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs) by first starting it with `./ngrok http http://localhost:5001` (check your `firebase.json` in order to see what port your `emulators.functions` are exposed, in my case was port 5001)
- This will output two `URLs`, with the following format `https://[TWILIOADRESS].ngrok.io`
- In order to be able to invoke the implemented `https function` via its unique URL, append this to the provided ngrok URL: `[project-id]/[project-implemented-region]]/[cloud-function-name]`
- You will end up with an `URL` that looks like this:

```
https://92003e41ecb0.ngrok.io/my-project-id/us-central1/cloudFunctionToExecute
```

- Now you can make a request (from postman, in my case) to the exposed function emulator using this URL
- If everything went alright, you should see some logs on the terminal where the emulators are running that tell you the function was executed, such as:

```
 functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-cloudFunctionToExecute
```

- You can also check status and metrics information about connections made over your tunnel from the UI terminal provided when you start ngrok. ngrok provides a real-time web UI where you can introspect all of the HTTP traffic running over your tunnels. After you've started ngrok, just open `http://localhost:4040` in a web browser to inspect request details