# Question about HTTP and Firebase functions

Tags: http, axios, google-cloud-functions

I've got a strange problem with axios requests made from my backend hosted on Firebase functions.

When I call my endpoint that looks like this: http://123.212.2.1:3001/message; from Postman it doesn't have any problem and it works like a charm.
But when I call this endpoint from my Firebase backend nothing works...it looks like the call just freeze and do not go on with execution.

Is the a problem if I call an HTTP and not an HTTPS url from Firebase? Or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT #1: Adding more details

This is the code of my API endpoint written in my firebase functions backend:

```
app.post("/callserver", async (req, res) => {
    await axios.get('http://123.212.2.1:3001/message', {
        message: "HELLO"
    })

    return res.status(200).json({
        message: "I DID IT"
    })
})
```

This is the api I'm trying to fetch from my personal server. This server is in another machine in my house.

```
app.get('/message', async (req,res) => {
  console.log('Server called at: ', new Date);
  res.status(200).json({
     message: "DONE"
  })
})
```

When I call directly the endpoint of my server from Postman it gives me this response:

```
{
    "message": "DONE"
}
```

When I call the endpoint of my firebase functions emulators it gives me this response here:
[image]

But when I try to call the deployed version of my firebase functions it just loads forever and nothing happens.
Can you tell me why?

Comment: Free plan or Blaze?

Comment: I'm currently using Blaze plan

Comment: Please add more details. Could you post your sample Postman and Axios request so we can reproduce the error? Please make sure that your sample does not include sensitive information like Project IDs, Auth Tokens, API Keys, etc.

Comment: Ok I'm going to edit my question. Thanks for the feedback and the suggestions

Comment: @Dondi I edited as you asked! Please ask more information if you need it so that I can be helpful to you while you help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I can see you're trying to self host your own Firebase Functions using the emulator. Wouldn't it be easier to simply deploy it and use the URL given to you by Firebase? Also, this sounds related to what you want to achieve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64822736/how-to-share-a-link-to-a-firebase-development-environment-when-using-firebase-em

Comment: No I’m not trying to selfhost. I’ve got a backend hosted with Firebade and another Server that I run in another machine. When I call the function deployed on firebase it loads forever while it’s trying to call an endpoint in my personal server. I’m using emulators only for development purposes

Comment: I'm not sure if I can reproduce this issue, but one way to know what's wrong is by checking debug logs. Check out [axios-debug-log](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-debug-log) and see if it helps.